# need cart data just after Add to cart action

Tags: magento-1.7, product, checkout, cart, bundled-product

i need cart data just after Add to cart action in magento

i need bundle product price after Add to cart action and before it's show in cart

i need bundle product total Price when **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaibhav,you can   get item price using `getOriginalPrice()` function `quote  item object`.

You can use `checkout_cart_product_add_after` or `checkout_cart_update_items_after` events

Comment: is it give me total price of bundleproduct